# How to detect video source size change?

Tags: video, http-live-streaming, video.js, live, m3u8

I'm using video.js to play a live hls video (m3u8 file), but the video size changes. Is there a way to know when the video size change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this checking for changes:

```
        var currentBitrate = qualityLevels[qualityLevels.selectedIndex].bitrate;
...snip

        if(currentBitrate >0){
           //see if the bitrate has changed?
           var oldBitrate = currentBitrate;
           currentBitrate = qualityLevels[qualityLevels.selectedIndex].bitrate;
           if(oldBitrate != currentBitrate){
              //bitrate has changed, do your thing.
           }
```

I have this running in this [Github Project](https://github.com/dougsillars/StreamOrNot) which is live at https://dougsillars.github.io/StreamOrNot/